# Using columns in Wordpress page that include header

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm a little bit of a newb when it comes to PHP, but know enough to get around and would like to know if this can be done. [sample](http://www.studio7thirteen.com/images/studio7thirteen2.jpg)

I want to break my wordpress page into 2 columns, but also want to have the header in the 1st column.... along with other text. I don't want the header floating over both columns...

The second column will house images only...

is that possible? In my head it makes sense, but then when I try and work it out, I'm just not sure....

And I just got thinking... I have my home page static with the smooth slider on it, so that is now going to cause more grief.

Any help, advice or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more CSS/HTML than PHP, however that's fine. The first thing you need to do is understand [how to make a two column layout](http://www.thesitewizard.com/css/design-2-column-layout.shtml). Then you will need to have the post title in the first column, something like this:

```
<article>
    <div id="col1">
        <h1>Post Title</h1>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
    </div>
    <div id="col2">
        <img src="" />
    </div>
</article>
```

To make this into WordPress you will of course need to add the WordPress Tags:

```
<div id="col1">
    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
</div>
```

Finally, adding the image(s) on the right. It can be done easily using [WordPress' built in functionality](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail), if you only need one image: *(Note you will have to add something in your theme's `functions.php` file as [per the WordPress Docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail))*

```
<div id="col2">
    <?php 
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
        the_post_thumbnail();
    } 
    ?>
</div>
```

To add multiple images, it gets more complex and you'll have to start looking for a plugin to achieve that goal.

Comment: Thanks Nick, that seemed to do the trick, though I am at the point where I am in col2 and would like to have multiple images since it will be kind of a portfolio type deal... I'm hoping to have 2-4 images on that side.

You don't by anychance know of any plugins off hand that would achieve that do you?

Comment: [Multiple Post Thumbnails](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/multiple-post-thumbnails/), the [install section](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/multiple-post-thumbnails/installation/) goes into how to include it on your site. Just as a side note, [on StackOverflow, if you use the answer, you should click the checkmark next to the question.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: ;) hit the checkmark... thank you so much for your help. you rock